# Extend USB ports on a smart phone

Tags: microcontroller, usb, smartphones

I want to connect a microcontroller to my smartphone through its(smartphone) only available micro USB port, and at the same time enable charging and data sync capability of the phone with the PC or other external devices through another micro usb port.

I know there are micro usb hub available in the market but the problem with them is that I can not connect a PC (to any of the hub's downstream ports) to charge and sync data through a downstream port simultaneously.

So I was thinking to add a microcontroller with 2 USB channels in the following way.
[image]

So I was looking for a feedback/suggestion on 
(1) Whether the microcontroller could be programmed in such a manner so that it could pass data from one USB port to another identifying the type(host/otg) of device connected to it? 
(2) For charging the smartphone can a microcontroller with inbuit battery detect/charger feature could be used for the same?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it unavoidably depends on details of **unspecified and potentially undocumented** synch protocols of an **unidentified consumer product**

Comment: @ChrisStratton, the Android OTG function is present on pretty much all smartphones. The complexity of the rest is outlined in my answer, there is no need on any particular details.

Comment: @AliChen - Nothing in the question says it is about Android.  But if it is, then it's all but unanswerable *as Android infamously lacks a traditional USB data synch mechanism*.  OTG, of course has **absolutely nothing** to do with synching with a PC, and in fact is an operating mode **mutually exclusive** with doing so.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I don't know what the "data synch" means, nor do I care. In any case this is something high in application level of network model. I am merely addressing difficulties in basic USB transport level, whether *"it could pass data from one USB port to another"*, I don't care much what kind of data the OP wants to transmit, it is inconsequential. If one can't provide clear transport level, the concerns about poorly-defined higher levels make no sense, your concern makes no sense at all.

Comment: @AliChen - the point (and reason the question must be closed if not edited) is that even after investing in hardware, the poster still won't be able to meet their goal, **or even determine if their goal is achievable at all** until they identify and study the actual traffic to be moved.  If this were *transparent* pass through, they wouldn't need USB interfaces at all but merely a wire or USB A/B switch chip.  Instead it is combining distinct streams, and we have no evidence that their phone platform permits that.

Answer (score 0):

This only works for USB 3.1 Type-C.

All older USB types do not support this. Since the phone must be Host to use OTG, and Device to charge.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157856/simultaneous-usb-otg-and-charging

Comment: Even then, it still won't work, as the asker wants the USB port to operate in two data roles *at once* and that just isn't possible.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Type C is capable of this, see all the laptop docks with Type C.

Comment: no, it's not.  In a laptop dock, the laptop may be receiving power, but in terms of data it is *only* being a host.  Here, the phone needs to be both a host and a device at the same time, and that isn't supported.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The type-c docks offer USB hub/HDMI out and have the charger input. Laptop will charge through the dock. Dock is a device, with power delivery.

Comment: **You are still confusing power and data**.  Irrespective of power flow, in terms of data, the laptop is only a USB host.  But the asker here needs the phone to be both a USB host and a USB device *at the same time*.  And that's not something USB supports - it can be either of these things at *different* times, but not at the *same* time.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That is not possible indeed. But not what was asked, asker need dynamic detection of host/device mode...

Comment: @ChrisStratton, where did you get an impression that OP wants *"phone to be both a USB host and a USB device at the **same time**"*? He just need an "accessory charger", that's it.

Comment: @AliChen by reading the actual text of the question...   But if in your belief the question doesn't require intercepting and parsing or modifying the data flow, then why do you propose a processor with dual USB interfaces?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, why dual USB interfaces? Because the downstream is asked to be "host/device", and therefore the upstream must also be able to have the data roles reversed. That't why two OTG. This is the only one omission in OP question, that the upstream also must  have a dual-role-data capability, to maintain the USB conceptual control down or up across the phone-peripheral link.

Comment: @AliChen - your lack of practical knowledge of phone operating systems is really showing here.  There's no standard functionality for controlling such a kludge.  So either you have what is basically a **switch** that just connects the USB lines without modifying the data, or else you're building something **intimately coupled to unstated details of the unidentified phone's unidentified operating system**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, you are saying an obvious nonsense. A gadget (Phone, Tablet, whatever) can be either a standard USB host and therefore support certain (if not all) device classes via classic USB framework, or it is a device, a mass storage or MTP. Or anything else like USB debug port. This is all under USB standard, phones "support" both functions, it is called "OTG", and any reference to "unidentified operating system" is inconsequential. Who gives a hoot how the USB functionality is implemented. And yes, you can just pass the USB wires through, and let MCU to handle the ID pin.

Comment: @AliChen - the question is **utterly unanswerable** until the asker specifies how the USB is to be **used**.  For all we know, it's enough to simply pass the data and ID lines through to the outside world.  What is **patently absurd** is your proposal to insert an intermediate processor in the data path **when you proudly disclaim any interest in what that should actually do**.  Seriously, how can you recommend a solution when **the problem is yet to be stated?**  Hardware is a container for software; until you can explain what the software should do, the hardware is useless.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, *"For all we know, it's enough to simply pass the data "* except the OP wants some sort of hub on the other end, which can't be accomplished with simple wires.

Comment: **The fatal problem is the words "some sort"**.  If it's a standard hub, they can buy one.  If it's a non-standard hub, **then it should be beyond obvious that they cannot build it without a functional spec**.  What should do it do?  If it should alter the data, how? to what end?  Under what conditions?  Until you have answers to this **grounded in factual statements by the asker** you are merely spouting tangential nonsense.

Comment: @ChrisStratton this much discussion tells us something about the quality of the question...

Comment: @Jeroen3 specifically it tells us that the question is unanswerable due to lack of critically necessary information.  *Speculation* is not supposed to have a role here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done, theoretically, under certain "boundary conditions".

A smartphone with USB micro-B port should support the [**standard OTG function**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/377131/117785), with ID pin that controls the data direction of the smartphone. This standard function also simultaneously controls the direction of VBUS: in host role the VBUS is supplied (therefore no charging), and in device mode the phone will accept charge.

If you need to have the roles "mixed" up (get the phone to be charged while in host mode), the phone must support this feature called "accessory charging mode". The mode should be engaged if the [ID pin impedance to ground is 20k or 120k](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/247991/117785). 
So the upstream link must conform to "accessory charger mode". This is regarding the second part of the question.

Regarding the first part, you have to have a sizable MCU like 32-bit STM32, with two (!) USB OTG controllers (since you indicate the bottom link as "USB Upstream/Downstream" as well. This means that MCU must have FOUR controllers, two of HOST type, and TWO of device type. I am not sure if such a monster does exist.

For the "upstream" OTG link you will need to have two GPIOs to control the state of ID pin (grounded, floating, or 120k), which will need some analogish circuitry. To transmit this information from your MCU to phone, you will need a proprietary 5-wire cable, with ID pin connection. These cables only exist for automated testers. And then write software to control the mode.

Then you will need to write a ton of bridging software to manipulate all four controllers in accord, and channel the data. You will need to decide on (invent and implement) internal communication protocols, depending to what extent do you want the devices to be transparent to standard USB framework. So one-two years of work for a team of USB architect, a hardware engineer, and a software engineer, and you are done. Good luck.

Comment: MCU's with two USB ports each of which can be *either* a host or device are not all that uncommon (the spec sheets would not refer to them as having four interfaces, but rather two dual-role interfaces).   However, this is unlikely to be practical as implementing a pass through for the various modes is rather complicated.  Further, the question is **off topic** here until those modes can actually be specified.  It's by no means clear that the phone OS will allow multiplexing anything with the unspecified synch protocol.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, would you care to provide a name/link to any processor with TWO OTG interfaces? Your uncanny contribution will be much appreciated. Regarding *"unlikely to be practical as implementing a pass through for the various modes is rather complicated"*, isn't my entire answer is all about the project being hugely complicated?

Comment: The point you're missing is that it's not clear that there's *any* phone with an openly documented protocol for generic PC data synch - android for example notoriously lacks this, so if the poster means mass storage or PTP or something then they need to say explicitly that, otherwise presumably they mean something that does have a data synch mechanism, albeit proprietary, like an iphone or maybe some **non-standard vendor-specific extension** of Android.  As for processors, the STM32F407/417 are an obvious example.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, obvious example? Do you call a 20-years-old FS (12 Mbps) interface as USB interface? Are you joking, right? You can't transfer any modern files with that in a reasonable time, yet to "data sync" anything. So, there is no real MCU with two OTG. Even the Chinese "Allwiner H5", a full-blown quad-core processor for phones and tablets, has ONE OTG (although 3 hosts), https://androidtvbox.eu/allwinner-h5-quad-core-cortex-a53-processor-designed-4k-tv-boxes-deatails/

Comment: Since the asker *still* hasn't specified what they want to do in the way of sync or even the phone OS, we don't know that full speed is unsuitable. Since you want to make this about Android, I'd point out that just about every "DIY I/O gadget connected to Android" project has been full speed, especially where the gadget had to play the host role. Even with dual high speed interface (vs the one high speed interface that that STM32 has along with its full speed one), it's doubtful that a microcontroller (vs. a system on a chip) could juggle data between fast enough to leverage that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, it doesn't matter what OP wants to do with data path. Usually "data synch" means a dump of some data structures or the entire file system into something outside the phone, which means a lot of data. By today's measure the FS is a joke, and DIY projects are just learning toys. And any reputable MCU, including your lovely STM32, has DMA engines to transfer data without much "juggling", only by managing few pointers.

Comment: as someone who's *actually done* Android *system* development, there's in practice very little difference between using a high speed host, and a VM running in software that limits it to full speed.  You only just notice it when doing a gigabyte scale system re-image.  And the reason is because Android isn't really designed to leverage the theoretical USB bandwidth.  Android is fundamentally designed for *cloud* sync - the USB support for PC connection is a very rudimentary afterthought.  Typically either mass storage or MTP is supported, but there's no actual framework for app-level "sync"